# Netbeans configuration - arguments not recognised in ide

Tags: configuration, netbeans, command-line-arguments, netbeans-6.9

I'm working my way through the Java in 24 hours book (which is actually quite good) and have hit a problem in that the simple test programs aren't recognising the arguments I put in the configuration window, i'm following the instructions exactly as written and have tried with different code snippets to no avail.

This is the latest script, note the 'No arguments println...

```
class newSqrt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 144;
        if (args.length > 0) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No arguments!");
        }
        System.out.println("The square root of "
            + number + " is " + Math.sqrt(number));
    }
}
```

I pasted a screenshot of the configuration clearly showing the argument 100 so I should see the square root of 100 but I get the output below clearly proving that it is just ignoring the argument from the configuration. I'm sure i'm not the only one who has had this happen, I have tried various google searches but nothing has helped track down the problem.

run:
No arguments!
The square root of 144 is 12.0
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Where exactly did you put the arguments in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-Click on the top-most node of your project in the *Projects* tab, and click on ***Properties***.

[image]

In the *Project Properties*, click on ***Run***, and then in *Arguments:* enter an appropriate value. Then click on ***OK***

[image]

Run the project by clicking on the ***Run*** toolbar button (or through the *Run* menu). If prompted for the main class, select newSqrt.  You should see the appropriate output.

[image]

Comment: Other things to check: if you are not prompted for the class with `main`, then go back in to the _Run_ configuration as above, and set it properly in the _Main Class_ field. If you have created several projects for different versions of the lesson, make sure the current lesson is the main project, not an earlier one. Either close all the other projects, or right-click on this project and click on _Set as Main Project_. Finally, close all sub-windows labeled "Output" to make sure you are not looking at old output (or make sure you click on the newest tab in that window).

Comment: One other thing... do a _Clean and Build Main Project_ on the _Run_ menu (after ensuring that the proper project is set as the main project), to make sure that you are running the latest code.

Comment: Thanks RobertB, Success, I tried two different code snippets that took different arguments and it worked just fine, I then reread the book and it does say to run file which is wrong, It is as you say run Project. Many thanks.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit strange that they didn't make "Run File" pass arguments too. I think "Run File" does not pass the "JVM Arguments" either. Apparently you can customize the ant file to do it, but that seems like way too much work to me, especially in your case.

Comment: BTW, I've noticed that you haven't "accepted" any answers you've asked here on stackoverflow. If the answer turns out to be the right one, then click on the check mark to accept it. It marks the question as answered.

Comment: RobertB, Sorry, I didn't know about that stackoverflow feature and have just set the green check mark.

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue. I have a Maven project, and I detected that "Run" arguments applying only after pressing "Build" project, simply run debug is not enough. Maybe bug in Netbeans.